# How to add OSGi WAR bundle ine eclipse target platform

Tags: osgi, eclipse-pde, target-platform

For my OSGi development i have setup a target definition (.target file) which references two directories. Eclipse picks up all the jar files inside these directories and adds them to the target platform. But one of the bundles i have is a WAR file (.war extension) which is run using pax-web. Eclipse doesn't show this in the list of bundles available. Is there any way to add a particular bundle directly into the target definition? Any way out that i might be missing? 
One workaround i found was to rename the .war file to .jar. Pax-web doesn't care about the extension, eclipse picks it up and so everything runs fine. But i am not very convinced if this is the right solution.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if you can accept an answer if you think your question was answered...

Answer (score 1):

Bug 355890 was fixed for 3.8/4.2.  You can now include archive files that are not jars (i.e. WAR files).

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug filed on eclipse on this very issue. Until it is fixed, the only workaround is to rename the file to have the .jar extension.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355890